# How to use SlideTransition defined on a different page on the other page in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-animation

I'm not even sure I chose the right title for my problem.
I designed a one home page, this home page has 2 different widgets. I separated these widgets into 2 different dart files to avoid writing dirty code. When I write all the codes on a single page, I can reach what I want. But when I separate the 2 pages, I have a problem that I can't solve.

**Here's what I want. On line 57 of my dart file named DashboardWidget, there is a `GestureDetector 'ontap' function`.
I change my `'isMenuOpen'` variable value with this button. When I press this button and change my `isMenuOpen value to true & false`,I want to change two different animations in two different files via this value. So every time the 'ontap' function is triggered, my DashboardWidget animation to change between forward/reverse. Also, simultaneously, my MenuWidget animation to change between forward/reverse.**

`[This is the image I want]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQEZN.png)

`[And this is the screen I see.]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdUfN.png)

I hope I have explain myself well. English is not my first language and I am newbie to programming.
Thank you in advance.

## home_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidermenu_and_dashboard/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidermenu_and_dashboard/widgets/dashboard_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidermenu_and_dashboard/widgets/menu_widget.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Constants.dashboardBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            DashboardWidget(),
            MenuWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## menu_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidermenu_and_dashboard/constants/constants.dart';

class MenuWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const MenuWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MenuWidget> createState() => _MenuWidgetState();
}

class _MenuWidgetState extends State<MenuWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<Offset> slideTransitionAnimation;
  late AnimationController animationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    slideTransitionAnimation =
        Tween(begin: const Offset(-1, 0), end: const Offset(0, 0)).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn),
    );
    animationController.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: slideTransitionAnimation,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 240),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              buildMenuItem('Dashboard', Icons.wallet_outlined),
              buildMenuItem('Messages', Icons.message_outlined),
              buildMenuItem('Utility Bills', Icons.document_scanner),
              buildMenuItem('Fon Transfer', Icons.compare_arrows_outlined),
              buildMenuItem('Branches', Icons.home_work_outlined),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildMenuItem(String title, IconData icon) {
    return ListTile(
      selectedTileColor: Colors.white,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      leading: Icon(icon, color: Constants.iconColor),
      title: Text(title, style: Constants.menuTextStyle),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

## dashboard_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidermenu_and_dashboard/constants/constants.dart';

class DashboardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<DashboardWidget> createState() => _DashboardWidgetState();
}

class _DashboardWidgetState extends State<DashboardWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isMenuOpen = false;
  late Animation<double> scaleAnimation;
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    scaleAnimation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.7).animate(animationController);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      left: isMenuOpen ? 0.4 * Constants.getScreenWidth(context) : 0,
      top: 0,
      right: isMenuOpen ? -0.3 * Constants.getScreenWidth(context) : 0,
      bottom: 0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: scaleAnimation,
        child: Material(
          borderRadius:
              isMenuOpen ? BorderRadius.circular(25) : BorderRadius.zero,
          elevation: isMenuOpen ? 12 : 0,
          color: Constants.dashboardBackground,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 8, right: 12),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (isMenuOpen) {
                            animationController.reverse();
                          } else {
                            animationController.forward();
                          }
                          isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    const Text('Dashboard'),
                    const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                height: 200,
                child: PageView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Here is the version of all my codes on a single page. As I said, this way the application works as I want. But when I move the methods named menuWidget and dashboardWidget to different dart files, the widget named menuWidget does not work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidermenu_and_dashboard/constants/constants.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isMenuOpen = false;
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation<double> scaleAnimation;
  late Animation<Offset> slideTransitionAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    scaleAnimation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.7).animate(animationController);
    slideTransitionAnimation =
        Tween(begin: const Offset(-1, 0), end: const Offset(0, 0)).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Constants.dashboardBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            menuWidget(),
            dashboardWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  menuWidget() {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: slideTransitionAnimation,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 240),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              buildMenuItem('Dashboard', Icons.wallet_outlined),
              buildMenuItem('Messages', Icons.message_outlined),
              buildMenuItem('Utility Bills', Icons.document_scanner),
              buildMenuItem('Fon Transfer', Icons.compare_arrows_outlined),
              buildMenuItem('Branches', Icons.home_work_outlined),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildMenuItem(String title, IconData icon) {
    return ListTile(
      selectedTileColor: Colors.white,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      leading: Icon(icon, color: Constants.iconColor),
      title: Text(title, style: Constants.menuTextStyle),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }

  dashboardWidget() {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      left: isMenuOpen ? 0.4 * Constants.getScreenWidth(context) : 0,
      top: 0,
      right: isMenuOpen ? -0.3 * Constants.getScreenWidth(context) : 0,
      bottom: 0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: scaleAnimation,
        child: Material(
          borderRadius:
              isMenuOpen ? BorderRadius.circular(25) : BorderRadius.zero,
          elevation: isMenuOpen ? 12 : 0,
          color: Constants.dashboardBackground,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 8, right: 12),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (isMenuOpen) {
                            animationController.reverse();
                          } else {
                            animationController.forward();
                          }
                          isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    const Text('Dashboard'),
                    const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                height: 200,
                child: PageView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Update

I've made some progress looking for the source of the problem.

```
GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (isMenuOpen) {
                            animationController.reverse();
                          } else {
                            animationController.forward();
                          }
                          isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
                    )
```

As you can see 'animationController.forward();' command is only in the DashboardWidget class. When I move it to a different page, there is no animation launcher command in my MenuWidget class. To solve this, I started a other 'animationController.forward();' command in the initState line in my MenuWidget class.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    slideTransitionAnimation =
        Tween(begin: const Offset(-1, 0), end: const Offset(0, 0)).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn),
    );
    animationController.forward();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Now I can see the widget named MenuWidget on the screen. But it's holding steady now. I want to make this animation dynamic with the 'ontap' command in the DashboardWidget class. So every time the 'isMenuOpen' value changes, my animation will switch between 'forward' and 'reverse' commands. I don't know where to write these commands (forward, reverse).

Answer (score 0):

```
SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            const DashboardWidget(isMenuOpen: false),
            MenuWidget(slideTransitionAnimation: slideTransitionAnimation),
           
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Can you try swapping your Dashboard Widget with MenuWidget? Because in stack you can see the last item on the top

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately there was no change.

Comment: I have an update to the question. You can have a look if you want to take a look.